# Maya Python: keep faces together based on hard edges

Tags: python, scripting, maya

I'm pretty new to all this so bear with me. I am learning Python for use with Maya and just got an idea but I can't wrap my head around how to go about it.

Let's say I have a cube with 2 subdivisions on each side. I now select all faces of the cube and extrude them. Maya gives me two options at this point for keeping faces together: `on` or `off`.
`Off` will result in each face to be extruded separately, while `on` will perform the extrude on all faces together.

What I want Maya to do is, to keep faces together turned on but turn it off as it hits an edge with a certain angle. So for example, I want to define an edge angle with an `intField()`, lets say 90 degrees, then pass the value to the extrude command. The result would be an `inset` for each of the six sides of the cube.

I know how to query an `intField()` and use its value to work with a button command but I just can't figure out how to pass the value to the extrude command.

David

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far ? some snippet ?

Comment: i deleted what i had, since it was all wrong.